# How to sort list items based on id attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, attributes

Hello so I have this problem, I use magento and my I can't find a place how to switch my tabs in position so I thought JQuery could come in hand. So this is what i have as an example

```
<li id="tab-4">
<li id="tab-3">
<li id="tab-2">
<li id="tab-1">
```

And i need to make it

```
<li id="tab-1">
<li id="tab-2">
<li id="tab-3">
<li id="tab-4">
```

Is there a fast way to do it? Or I have to do it one by one?

Comment: And, Where is your slower method?

Comment: Are you trying to update the magento code that generates this page or are you looking or a function that does this after magento already rendered the page?

Comment: I am trying to do it after as I am using Porto template and custom tabs and I can't even find how to disable default tabs. So it would be just easier to switch after page load

Comment: @PovilasJasilionis if any of the answers sovled your question you should mark it as answer to inform other users what the solution was

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have an `<ul>` around you `<li>`

```js
ul = $('ul'); // your parent ul element
ul.children().each(function(_,li){ul.prepend(li)})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="tab-4">4</li>
<li id="tab-3">3</li>
<li id="tab-2">2</li>
<li id="tab-1">1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would be even better if you would replace unused `i` variable with `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS solution.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var b = document.getElementById('list');
var arr = [];

Array.from(a).forEach(v => arr.push(v));
arr.reverse().forEach(v => b.append(v));
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li id="tab-4">4</li>
  <li id="tab-3">3</li>
  <li id="tab-2">2</li>
  <li id="tab-1">1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for a sollution working (actually sorting) regardless of the initial order you can use `sort()` and `append` like this:

```js
$("ul li").sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.id.substring(4, 5) < b.id.substring(4, 5)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}).each(function() { $('ul').append(this);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="tab-4">4</li>
  <li id="tab-1">1</li>
  <li id="tab-3">3</li>
  <li id="tab-2">2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".list > li").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.id.replace("tab-","") - b.id.replace("tab-","") ;
    }).appendTo("ul.list");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
<li id="tab-3">3
<li id="tab-4">4
<li id="tab-2">2
<li id="tab-1">1
</ul>
```

If your HTML code like this you can write your code using detach and a single appendTo like this.

More about detach(): https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_detach.asp